# Keep movement of vertexShader despite of its mesh rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js, vertex-shader

I'm simply moving the vertices of my cube following the y axis.

It works fine but when I start rotating my cube, the movements stays at the global y axis. Does anyone know how to prevent this behavior? Meaning having the rotation and the movement of my vertices separated?

https://codepen.io/michaelgrc/pen/JjrMVPm?editors=0010

```c
void main()
{
    vec4 modelPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

    float deplacement = sin(uTime) * 2.;
    modelPosition.y += deplacement;

    vec4 viewPosition = viewMatrix * modelPosition;
    vec4 projectedPosition = projectionMatrix * viewPosition;

    gl_Position = projectedPosition;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "having the rotation and the movement of my vertices separated"? Do you want to translate and than rotate?

Comment: thanks for your answer. The idea is having my initial movement of vertices (only having my top and bottom faces moving up and down) and then make the whole mesh rotating as if it was in a group. But I tried it using a group and I have the same result : so far the movement of up and down keeps at the global y axis.

Comment: Of course you can use a Group. You have to rotate The Group and tranalte the mesh in the group.

Comment: The simple translation was here to illustrate my issue. I'm planing to do a more complex movement in a more complexe mesh :)

Comment: So you need to use a group as suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix operations are not [Commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). What you actually do is translate the model after applying the `modelMatrix`:

```
v' = translate * modelMatrix * v;
```

However you have to apply the tranaltion first:

```
v' = modelMatrix * translate * v;
```

e.g.:

```c
void main()
{
    mat4 translate = mat4(1.0);
    translate[3].y = sin(uTime) * 2.0;
    vec4 modelPosition = modelMatrix * translate * vec4(position, 1.0);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelPosition;
}
```

---

Note, the same can be achieved with a [Group](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Group). The rotation has to be applied to the *Group* and the translation to the *Mesh* in the *Group*.

```js
group = new THREE.Group();
group.add(mesh);
```

```js
mesh.position.y = offset;
group.rotation.x = angle_x;
group.rotation.y = angle_y;
```

Comment: I tried to apply your question but my displacement still depends on the global meshes position. I edited my question with a very simple codepen example. Do you see what I'm missing ? I think I shouldn't apply my modelPosition.x on line 38 but I don't know what to add instead. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Michaël You have to ask a new question. [Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).