# Apply a vertex shader on a mesh, independently of its position

Tags: javascript, three.js, vertex-shader

I'd like to apply some movements on my meshes using a vertex-shader. I noticed that when I translate my meshes in my scene it also moves the position of my simple sinus wave.
I'd like to have the same sinus wave on both my meshes even if I translate my meshes in my scene.

I had a first lead with this post : [Keep movement of vertexShader despite of its mesh rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70510964/keep-movement-of-vertexshader-despite-of-its-mesh-rotation)

I tried to reproduce this solution but I'm missing something. Here's my shader :

```
        uniform float uTime;
        
        void main()
        {
            mat4 translate = mat4(1.0);

            vec4 modelPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
            
            translate[3].y = sin(uTime * 2. + modelPosition.x *1.);

            vec4 modelPosition2 = modelMatrix * translate * vec4(position, 1.0);

            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelPosition2;
        }
```

I think I shoudn't apply my modelPosition.x on the translate[3].y line but I don't know what to call instead. As you can see on this codepen, my planes look different : https://codepen.io/michaelgrc/pen/GRMxYBm

Does anyone see what I'm missing ? Thanks a lot

Comment: `translate[3].y = sin(uTime * 2. + position.x.);` ? I don't know your final goal though.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use `position.x` instead of `modelPosition.x` to solve my issue :

```
translate[3].y = sin(uTime * 2. + position.x);
```